# Can two verbs have the same direct object?

Tags: direct-objects

> I’ll do whatever it takes to get the job.

Is *whatever* a direct object for *do* and *takes*?

Comment: *Whatever* is the direct object of *takes* (it's a bit complicated), but it is *not* the object of *do*. The object of *do* is the entire noun phrase *whatever it takes* (a fused relative construction).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Just a few days ago, you were claiming that the antecedent of a relative clause cannot be the subject or object of the verb in the relative clause. If so, how is _whatever_, which includes the antecedent, the object of _takes_?

Comment: @JK2 Yes, you're right ,I was being lazy. Hence my '(it's complicated)' bit, and hence only a comment. Let me redo that.

Comment: @John I was oversimplifying in my original comment. In the fused relative construction *whatever it takes to get the job*, there is no overt direct object of the verb *take*. Instead there is a gap where the overt direct object would be in a normal clause. *whatever it takes ___ to get the job.* The listener understands that the missing element refers to the same thing as the *wh*-word, in this case *whatever.* [In many modern grammars, the direct object of *take* actually *is* the gap - e.g. in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*]

Comment: @Araucaria Please **write an answer.** Doing so helps everyone, including the software which will know when a question has been answered.

Comment: _He hit, and shattered, the vase._ Two verbs ; one direct object.

Answer (score 4):

> (1) *I’ll do whatever it takes to get the job.*

As @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. has commented, the direct object of *do* is not *whatever* but the entire noun phrase *whatever it takes to get the job*, because what you'll do is not just whatever or whatever it takes to get a different job but whatever it takes to get the job.

Now, although @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. argues otherwise in the comment, we can say that the direct object of *takes* is *whatever*.

H&P's *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 1038) says this about *I accepted the advice* [***which** my neighbour gave me* ____]:

> In the first instance it is the gap that is in object function, as indicated in the diagram. However, prenuclear elements that are linked to a gap are interpreted as having the function of that gap, and we can thus say in a secondary, derivative, sense that they have that function. On this account, therefore, ***which* is object of the relative clause**, just as it is in traditional grammar.

(Boldface mine.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144801/discussion-on-answer-by-jk2-can-two-verbs-have-the-same-direct-object); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

> I’ll do whatever it takes to get the job.
>
> Is whatever a direct object for do and takes?

No.

“Whatever it takes” is the direct object of "do" = “Whatever [action] **that** it takes/requires”

Thus “it takes” is relative/adjectival and modifies “Whatever”.

to get the job. = **in order** to get the job.

*in order to get the job* is an adverbial phrase modifying "takes".

If you want an example of two verbs with one object:

He took and ate the apple.

Answer (score 0):

[*Whatever it takes* is an idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whatever+it+takes), and here, it is the **direct object** of *do*:

> *I’ll do [**whatever it takes**] to get the job.*

You can compare it to:

> *I'll do [**anything**] to get the job.*

Comment: A more similar example would be: _I'll do anything it takes to get the job_, where the object of _do_ is not just _anything_ or _anything it takes_, but _anything it takes to get the job_. Similarly, _whatever it takes to get the job_ is the object in OP.

Comment: @JK2: You can say *anything that it takes*, but not *whatever that it takes*. So not so similar.

Comment: They're similar enough to show that they both have _to get the job_ as part of the object of _do_, whereas it's not part of the object in your own example.

Comment: No: "to get the job" is not part of the object of "do" but a separate constituent, a purpose adjunct. This is evident from the fact that "in order to" can be inserted, and also that "take" does not take a plain catenative complement, but only a complex one, the kind with an intervening NP.